# If $g: Y \to X$ is a torsor for a smooth linear algebraic group over a field and $X$ is smooth then is $Y$ also smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and let $X$ be an algebraic variety (seperated scheme of finite type) over $Spec(k)$. Let $G$ be a smooth linear algebraic group over $k$ and $g: Y \to X$ a torsor for $G$. So by definition $g$ is faithfully flat and locally of finite presentation.

My question is

> if $X$ is smooth over $k$ does it follow that $Y$ is also smooth over $k$?

Is my reasoning in favor of yes correct? Since smoothness if fpqc local on the base we just need to check it in the case $k = k^{alg}$ is algebraically closed. Since algebraic varieties are locally Noetherian we just need to check smoothness on closed points. The fibers $Y_x$ for closed points $x \in X$ are smooth since they are isomorphic to $G$. Since $g$ is flat and locally of finite presentation and the fibers over closed points are smooth it follows by Stacks Project Tag 01V8 ( https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V8 ) that $g$ is smooth. So $Y$ is smooth over $k$ since it is the composition of two smooth morphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to MSE:) and props for the nice, and nicely written, question!

As far as I can tell, your proof is correct! Put more succinctly, by hypothesis there exists an étale cover $U \twoheadrightarrow X$ of the base such that the base change $Y_U$ is isomorphic to the trivial $G_U$-torsor - in particular, $Y_U \cong G_U$ as a $U$-scheme. But then $Y_U \to U \to \text{Spec}(k)$ is smooth since it's a composition of smooth morphisms; thus so must $Y$ be as [smoothness descends via fpqc morphisms](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02VL).

Hope this helps and I didn't mess something up :P

Comment: Your proof is very nice and clear!